# How can I apply sorting on certain tables in a word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a system that generate test results reports for me. I managed to create the right table templates for the use of this system. But, for some reason the report, which is about 950 pages long full of tables and diagrams, was generated while the tables are sorted in a descending order. I have tried to make the auto reports to output the tables in an ascending order without success.

Then I started to look for a solution to this problem. One of the solution that I have is the following VBA code. But, when I apply it on the whole report it gets stuck and Word turns to "Not Responding". I am completely new to VBA and don't see the reason. Can you please tell me why ?

```
Attribute VB_Name = "SortTable_Ascend"
Sub Find_Text_in_table()

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Step"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute

        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then

            Selection.Tables(1).SortAscending

        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

By the way, I only look for certain tables (the ones that have a column with the string "Step" in them) and apply the sorting on them. When I took only 100 pages of this document and applied this script it did the job and didn't get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should process a bit faster and will get through all tables.

```
Sub Find_Text_in_table()
Dim rng As word.Range, tbl As word.Table
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = word.WdViewType.wdNormalView
Application.Options.Pagination = False
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    Set rng = tbl.Range
    rng.Find.ClearFormatting
    With rng.Find
        .Text = "Step"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute
        If .found Then
            If rng.InRange(tbl.Range) Then
                tbl.SortAscending
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = word.WdViewType.wdPrintView
Application.Options.Pagination = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. If I understand it right my script was wasting too much resources by focusing on the whole document and your script focuses only on the tables in the document ?

Comment: Unfortunately word immediately gets into the "Not Responding" status. I don't see any issues of RAM or CPU resources. Maybe the document is too big for this kind of task. Is there a way to make the script deal with separated chunks of the document ?

Comment: A Word not responding message does not necessary mean that a macro is not running. When documents, particularly those with many tables, get over 150 -200 pages, processing really slows down. While the routine is running check Task Masker and if the process is using CPU and Disk IO. Also add ... ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = word.WdViewType.wdNormalView ... to the beginning right after the Dim statements and then just before End Sub use the same command but change the view type to wdPrintView, We're trying to suppress document repagination as much as possible.

Comment: I forgot one command to also add, Application.Options.Pagination = False and turn it back to True at the end.

Comment: @Moshe See my responses above. Regarding your question about chunking the document in parts. That could be done by Sections, Bookmarks, Table Counts, and probably some other methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The sorting now took about 1.5 minutes. Great assistance

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that avoids the word find and replace.  It also uses the more general Sort method which replicates the dialog box you get when doing the sort in word.  This might be helpful if you want to sort on multiple columns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    SortTables_WithKey "Step"
End Sub

Sub SortTables_WithKey(this_key As String)

Dim myIndex                            As Long
Dim myLastTable                        As Long

    myLastTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Options.Pagination = False

    For myIndex = 1 To myLastTable
        ' MS have deprecated the use of statusbar so if this line
        ' but it still appears to work in Word 2016
        Application.StatusBar = "Table " & CStr(myIndex) & " of " & CStr(myLastTable)

        If InStr(ActiveDocument.Tables(myIndex).Range.text, this_key) > 0 Then
            ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.sort
            ' Replicates the type of sort when done using Word
            ActiveDocument.Tables(myIndex).Sort _
                excludeheader:=True, _
                fieldnumber:=1, _
                sortfieldtype:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, _
                sortorder:=wdSortOrderAscending

        End If

        DoEvents
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Options.Pagination = True

End Sub
```

Edited to revise the sub to include the recommendations about screen updating, events and pagination (others beat me to it).  I've also included code to put a message in the status bar (bottom left corner of the word window) which will show progress (Table x of y).  I tested the above on a document I have with 125 tables and (without sorting the tables) it completed in around 5 seconds.

I also corrected one error I made

```
sortorder:=wdSortAscending
```

should have been

```
sortorder:=wdSortOrderAscending
```

Hence the addition of 'option explicit' at the start of the code.

Comment: Unfortunately word immediately gets into the "Not Responding" status. I don't see any issues of RAM or CPU resources

Comment: I have tried my script on part of this report (by cutting it down to about 100 pages) and it did the job in several minutes

Comment: Add a doEvents just above `Next` - that should help make it stay responsive (but take longer). Alternatively you can disable screen updating

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub SortTables()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim t As Long, bfit As Boolean
With ActiveDocument
  For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
    With .Tables(t)
      If InStr(1, .Range.Text, "Step", 0) > 0 Then
        bfit = .AllowAutoFit
        If bfit = True Then .AllowAutoFit = False
        .SortAscending
        If bfit = True Then .AllowAutoFit = True
      End If
    End With
    If t Mod 100 = 0 Then DoEvents
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Turning off screen updating and the table autofit property will both enhance performance. Running DoEvents periodically on long operations also gives Word some breathing space.